# How to manage cache in iphone with codes

Tags: iphone

My Application requires a username and password fields.At the first login the validation working perfect.But the second time onwards there is no validation in the password field.It is automatically collected from the cache.
   I am using the below codes for requesting.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:                             [NSURL URLWithString:xmlUrl]                                     cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                    timeoutInterval:30.0];
```

[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
NSURLResponse* response = nil;

```
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest
                                       returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSDictionary* dict=[theRequest allHTTPHeaderFields];
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just use this line instead:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:xmlUrl]
                                            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                            timeoutInterval:30.0];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
```

Comment: Yes....I tried this codes also.But still now the same problem shows.Can you give me any other suggestions.                         In the log out page I used the below code .                    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

Comment: For requesting ,I used this much codes below
 NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:          [NSURL URLWithString:xmlUrl]          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
      timeoutInterval:30.0];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
NSURLResponse* response = nil;

 [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest
             returningResponse:&response error:&error];
 NSDictionary* dict=[theRequest allHTTPHeaderFields];